# packages were automatically installed and are no longer required

Tags: package-management

I installed sendEmail on Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS based on a recommendation from http://linuxneophyte.com/sendemail-a-light-and-simple-command-line-mailer/

The package installed (not visible with dpkg but /usr/bin/sendEmail exists) and that was followed by this prompt:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php-mail-mime php-net-socket php-mdb2-driver-mysql php-mdb2 libpango1.0-common php5-gd
  libmcrypt4 libt1-5 libhal1 php-net-smtp php5-pspell libhal-storage1 libaudiofile0
  php5-mcrypt php-auth dbconfig-common tinymce php-mail-mimedecode
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

Earlier, the above list of packages to remove included courier-ssl which I removed, but I'm not sure about the others. Should I keep these packages or remove them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195894/the-following-packages-were-automatically-installed-and-are-no-longer-required)

Answer (score 6):

You can safely remove these packages. They are no longer needed by the OS.

Comment: would the line of code "sudo apt-get autoremove" work?

Comment: Yes. That is the correct command.

Comment: Might still be needed when ZFS on root with snapshots? Or can one rule this out as well?